# keyboard shortcut to formula editing field (literally) in Excel? (Not F2)

Tags: excel

I am looking for the keyboard shortcut to edit a formula **in the formula edit field**. I am **not** looking for similar functionality such as F2, which allows you to edit the formula, but only with the cursor in the cell you are working on.

Put another way, I am looking to move my cursor to the field to the right of the "fx" (function sign + "x") field that is just below the ribbon so I can edit a formula in Excel and have it behave the way I want.

I know many will ask why. The main reason I want to do this is when formulas get long they wrap (which is difficult to follow) and/or cover up adjacent cells (which makes modeling more difficult). I don't want to change the wrapping behavior etc. because I actually use it (it is helpful) in some cases.

I do not want a solution that involves a macro because I want this to work on any computer I am working on.

Been Excel'ing for a long time and this is one of the few things I have to go to the mouse for and it slows me down.

EDIT: also can't lose the reference color coded highlighting. F2 then Ctrl + A gets the cursor up there in the formula bar, but the wrapping in the cell stays (bad) and the color coded reference highlighting goes away (bad).

Comment: Have you checked lists of keyboard shortcuts? That's essentially the only option you're accepting and it's an easy-to-Google solution. As far as I know this can't be done, I'd happily be shown otherwise though because this would be useful.

Comment: Yes, I have Googled it a lot and I agree it seems it is not possible as I discussed here today: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/990996-keyboard-shortcut-formula-editing-field-literally-excel-not-f2.html

Answer (score 1):

I found a way but you may or may not like it.

In Excel older than 2007 do the following and then use F2:

1. From the Tools menu, choose Options.
2. Click the Edit tab.
3. Uncheck the Edit Directly In Cell option in the Settings area.
4. Click OK

In Excel 2007 and newer do the following and then use F2:

1. Click the Office button and then click Excel Options (at the bottom
   right).
2. Select Advanced in the left pane.
3. Uncheck the Allow Editing Directly In Cell option.
4. Click OK.

Giving credit where credit is due I found this on the below site by simply googling "excel keyboard shortcuts formula bar"

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/quick-access-to-excel-formula-bar-via-keyboard/

Comment: I've seen that one. It removes the wrapping function and it requires someone to go into options twice if one is in Excel on someone else's computer: once to set it and once to remove it. I need to go directly into the formula bar I think, otherwise you either lose functionality or you get wrapping when you don't want it that covers up other cells. I discuss it here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/990996-keyboard-shortcut-formula-editing-field-literally-excel-not-f2.html

Comment: honestly i think you might have to just take you hand off your keyboard for about 1-2 seconds and click in the formula bar with your mouse. Sorry but I don't think Mircosoft thought that anyone would be that opposed to using a mouse.

Comment: Chad - I'm guessing you don't model in Excel very much or you don't use shortcuts often. It's more like 3 seconds by the time you find home row again on the keyboard. Compare that to 1/10 of a second (I am guessing) to not leave the keyboard. That's like 97% longer to use the mouse. If you model hardcore all day for 8 hours and you go to the mouse about 60 times in an hour (very reasonable), you just wasted 23 minutes that day moving your hand, not to mention lost continuity in your work. Any hardcore Excel'er worth a darn will tell you this. Ask anyone from Wall Street. (I'm in Finance.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the first comment. You want to do a one time change to your setting to "Edit Directly in Cell"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).